# Adding a new object with key value pairs in immutable object

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Here's a simple test I've written of what I want to do with an immutable object

```
it('adds a new map with loaded data where the key is the ticker symbol', () => {
        const state = Map();
        const tickers = List.of('AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOGL');
        const nextState = addTickerKeys(state, tickers);

        expect(nextState).to.equal(fromJS({
            tickers: ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOGL'], 
            data: {
                AAPL: {}, 
                TSLA: {}, 
                GOOGL: {}
            }
        }));
    })
```

How do I add the data object and the corresponding keys with empty data into the state object?

Here is what I have tried so far

```
export function addTickerKeys(state, tickers) {
    const newState = setTickers(state, tickers);
    const tickerList = newState.get('tickers');
    return tickerList.forEach((value, key, iter) => {
        return newState.setIn(['data', key]);
    })
}
```

I've tried substituting value, key and iter in place of return newState.setIn(['data', key]) as per the docs (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set)

However, I get the same response back each time,

> AssertionError: expected 3 to equal { Object (size, _root, ...) }

Can someone explain to me what's going wrong? This seems a simple enough task but I seem to be struggling with Immutable objects and the documentation in TypeScript doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick answer to this, that I just figured out.

Immutable does not seem to have a great inbuilt function for this task and the way you have to return the state from a pure function is just frustrating.

Here's a quick and dirty solution to adding the object key value pairs.

```
export function addTickerKeys(state) {
    const tickerArray = state.get('tickers');
    let newState = Map();
    for(let i = 0; i < tickerArray.size; i++){
        ctr++;
        newState = state.setIn(['data', tickerArray.get(i)], Map());
        state = state.concat(newState);
        if(i === tickerArray.size - 1){
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone else still has a different answer, a more elegant inbuilt solution perhaps do share.

Answer (score 1):

A quick comment on your first solution:

Much like the native `forEach` method on `Array.prototype`, the `forEach` method on immutable List types is used for executing some side effect upon each iteration of the List. One subtle difference between the two, however, is when the callback function returns false on the immutable `forEach`, it will immediately end execution of the loop, whereas the native `forEach` is interminable. Here, you utilize the `forEach` method on Lists but are returning a value, suggesting that you might have confused it with the `map` method on immutable types and arrays. Unfortunately, `map` is not what you're looking for either.

Now, another solution:

```
function addTickerKeys(state, tickers) {
  return tickers.reduce((acc, ticker) => {
    return acc.setIn([ 'data', ticker ], Map());
  }, Map({
    tickers: List(tickers),
  }))
}
```